# Use variable in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

My SQL statement in SQL Server looks like this:

```
DECLARE @forecastYear AS varchar(5)
    SET @forecastYear = '2020'
DECLARE @versionName AS varchar(25)
    SET @versionName = '20201113_wk'
DECLARE @currentMonth AS varchar(2)
    SET @currentMonth = (SELECT current_fc_month FROM tbl_current_month)
 SELECT f.record_id
     , u.it_ops_j_level_abbr_nm 
     , f.owner_nm 
     , f.unit_cd 
     , f.tbm_cd 
     , f.tower_nm 
     , f.description_txt 
     , f.comment_txt 
     , f.cost_pool_nm 
     , f.glac_nr 
     , f.glac_nm 
     , f.initiative_nm 
     , f.priority_nm 
     , f.growth_nm 
     , f.it_vendor_nm 
     , f.jan_amt 
     , f.feb_amt 
     , f.mar_amt 
     , f.apr_amt 
     , f.may_amt 
     , f.jun_amt 
     , f.jul_amt 
     , f.aug_amt 
     , f.sep_amt 
     , f.oct_amt 
     , f.nov_amt 
     , f.dec_amt 
  FROM tbl_new_forecast f
       INNER JOIN tbl_unit_tree u
               ON f.unit_cd = u.dept_id 
 WHERE f.version_nm = @versionName 
   AND f.status_cd = 'Approved'
   AND f.entry_type = 'Forecast'
   AND f.forecast_yr_id = @forecastYear 
   AND ABS(f.nov_amt)+ABS(f.dec_amt) <> 0
```

What I want to do is change the last statement in the WHERE clause based on the value in `@currentMonth`.
Therefore, if `@currentMonth` = '3' then the last statement would read

```
AND ABS(f.mar_amt)+ABS(f.apr_amt)+ABS(f.may_amt) <> 0
```

If `@currentMonth` = '7' then it would read

```
AND ABS(f.jul_amt)+ABS(f.aug_amt)+ABS(f.sep_amt) <> 0
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this, because I get a SQL error with this syntax:

```
AND CASE 
      WHEN @currentMonth = '10' THEN ABS(f.oct_amt)+ABS(f.nov_amt)+ABS(f.dec_amt) <> 0
    END
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like, in truth, you have a denormalised dataset. The month should be denoted by a column, you shouldn't have a single column for each month.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to fix the table design. Don't include one colum for each month, separate those into a new table containing month and the amount, joined to the main table.

Comment: Agreed, it is denormalized. Perhaps writing an unpivot query first would be the way to go?

Comment: Unpivoting your data could well help, yes. Some sample data, and expected results, would really help us, help you.

Comment: apart from changing the organization of your tables, what you're looking for can be done by dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Iraj that's what I'm looking for help on. The syntax is not working, so I need help with getting it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a solution, a complex `WHERE` clause is an option. Note, that in T-SQL `CASE` is an expression, not a statement:

```
AND ( 
    ((@currentMonth = 1) AND (ABS(f.jan_amt) + ABS(f.feb_amt) + ABS(f.mar_amt) <> 0)) OR
    ((@currentMonth = 2) AND (ABS(f.feb_amt) + ABS(f.mar_amt) + ABS(f.apr_amt) <> 0)) OR
    ...
    ((@currentMonth = 10) AND (ABS(f.oct_amt) + ABS(f.nov_amt) + ABS(f.dec_amt) <> 0)) OR
    ((@currentMonth = 11) AND (ABS(f.nov_amt) + ABS(f.dec_amt) <> 0)) OR
    ((@currentMonth = 12) AND (ABS(f.dec_amt) <> 0))
)
```

Comment: Very simple, thank you. Made me go "Duh!" after looking at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @month_dependent varchar (500)=' ';
DECLARE @main_query varchar(1000)=' ';
DECLARE @forecastYear AS varchar(5)
SET @forecastYear = '2020'
DECLARE @versionName AS varchar(25)
SET @versionName = '20201113_wk'
DECLARE @currentMonth  char(2)
SET @currentMonth = (SELECT current_fc_month FROM tbl_current_month)
If @currentMonth  =  '3' 
BEGIN set @month_dependent=' AND ABS(f.mar_amt)+ABS(f.apr_amt)+ABS(f.may_amt) <> 0 '; END
If @currentMonth  =  '7' 
BEGIN set @month_dependent=' AND ABS(f.jul_amt)+ABS(f.aug_amt)+ABS(f.sep_amt) <> 0 '; END

set @main_query varchar(1000)=' SELECT f.record_id' + 
  ' , u.it_ops_j_level_abbr_nm ' +
  -- ' and all the rest of it! ' +
  ' FROM tbl_new_forecast f '+
  ' INNER JOIN tbl_unit_tree u '+
  ' ON f.unit_cd = u.dept_id ' +
  ' WHERE f.version_nm = '''+ @versionName + ''' '+
  ' AND f.status_cd = ''Approved'' '+
  ' AND f.entry_type = ''Forecast'' '+
  ' AND f.forecast_yr_id = ''' + @forecastYear + ''' '+
    @month_dependent

EXECUTE sp_executesql @main_query ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this really complex by using a WHERE clause with a lot of ors in it:

```
AND ({first month condition} OR {Second month condition} OR {third month condition})
```

Etc. Another option is to place this into a stored procedure and use the month as the trigger to determine which statement to run. Depending on how you are running this, it might be a preferred method, as it can abstract out the details from the application (something you will want if you ever decide to normalize this data).

As for trying to use CASE in a WHERE clause, you have it wrong. The CASE WHEN has to equal something. The correct syntax is like:

```
AND SomeValue = CASE WHEN ...
```

You cannot simply use case, as a where is looking for equality (=), inequality (<>), and fuzzy values (LIKE). Thus, this does not work.

```
AND CASE WHEN ...
```

As an example, [this](https://www.essentialsql.com/can-i-have-a-case-statement-in-the-where-clause/) shows something that fires back 1 to get equivalent rows. But you would need all of your conditions in here, which means the WHEN on month and the ABS() would be the entire condition. You then return 1 to indicate "found it". But you are running this as a monthly query, so filtering by the month and then determining the CASE ... WHEN is where you go.